# show hidden table from PHP

Tags: php

Hi can some one please tell me whether I'm missing something in the following code which result in not showing up the hidden table? Thanks for looking.

```
    echo("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>document.getElementById('tblmain').style.display = 'block';</SCRIPT>");
```

Comment: Can you throw it in a JSFiddle with pertinent code?

Comment: Get any errors from the JS console? `tblmain` might not exist in the DOM yet.

Comment: @Zaffy : the table with the id 'tblmain' is hidden from the html code. What I'm trying to do is on the click of a button through PHP to bring back the table on screen. So here is my PHP code written for that which gives me a complete blank screen

Comment: @MohanWijesena But options to hide elements in html are huge. It can be css display, css visibility, css zindex, etc

Comment: @Zaffy : <table width="793" align="left" id="tblmain" style="display:none"> here how its there in the html. sorry for being not specific

Comment: @MohanWijesena and when your code gets called? Before or after the table is loaded?

Comment: @zaffy : Code is called before the table is loaded and the calling code (the PHP code mention above) intends to unhide the table.

Comment: @MohanWijesena and thats the problem. Your code will call when table doesnt exist. Wrap your code to `window.addEventListener("load", (function(){document.getElementById('tblmain').style.display = "block";}), false);` and window.attachEvent forIE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be BY FAR easier and more reliable to simply have

```
echo '<style type="text/css">#tblmain { display: block }</style>';
```

so you're not dependent on JS being available?

Comment: No. Read the comments. Table will override css with `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery try this:

```
echo("
            <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#tblmain').show();
                });
            </SCRIPT>"
        );
```

Note the `$(document).ready(function(){...});` It will fire code within when the whole DOM tree is ready. If it won't work it means #tblmain element doesn't exist.